# Expected Value question with a bound condition

Tags: probability

EDIT: to clarify the condition of the problem, I modified the wording of the problem.

> A person starts out with $d$ dollars. There is a box which he has to use exactly once every day, and he can put at most one thousand dollars into it each time he uses it. There is a 50% chance that it will return $1.6$ times the amount of money he put it, and there is a 50% chance that it will return $0.6$ times the amount of money he put it. The person cannot choose to put in less money than he can (for example, if he has $1200$ dollars, he cannot decide to put in $940$ dollars but must instead put in $1000$ dollars). At the end of $30$ days, what would be the expected value of the total money he has (a) if $d=1000$ and (b) if $d=2000$?

I know the formula for the expected value and the basics of probability theory. What makes this question difficult is that (1) he is not allowed to put in more money than $\$1000$, and (2) he may have less than $\$1000$ at some point of the day. If he can and must put all of the money he has each day, then the expected value after $n$ days would be $\frac{1000 \cdot (2.2)^n}{2^n} $ (please correct me if I am wrong). Of course I would be grateful if someone can provide me an answer without rote calculation and for the general $n$ days (rather than just $30$ days, which seems to be an arbitrary number of days).

Comment: I don't understand the preamble about the maximum and minimum daily purchases.  Since he starts with $\$1000$, say, doesn't he just buy one share of stock and then let's it ride?  No more options for him after that first day's purchase, right?  And if he starts at $\$2000$...well, then he must spend $1000$ each of the first two days, yes?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Also:   The expected value at the end of $30$ days is not the same as the value you get if you get the expected number of "up" days.  The problem is that the payouts are badly asymmetric...you can lose $\$1000$ at most, but you can win an enormous amount, so you must weigh the possible gains/losses against their probabilities.

Comment: I don't know how to easily compute this. What's the source of the problem?

Comment: @T_M from an acquiantance; he is studying for the Korean college entrance exam.

Comment: @lulu problem's wording changed to answer your inquires and/or to clear out confusion.

Comment: I don't see any meaningful changes.  The point is that the player's strategy is determined, there is no optionality.  Each day he must invest $\max (1000,B)$ where $B$ is the cash he has that day.  Thus you can just handle each day separately.

Comment: You mean "min" I think? If $B < 1000$ he invests $B$. Otherwise he has to invest exactly 1000$.

Comment: So if at beginning of day you have $B$. Then you hold back $(B - \min(1000,B))$ and invest $\min(1000,B)$. After the game you end up with $(B - \min(1000,B)) + \min(1000,B) X$ , where $X$ is the random variable that takes values 1.6 or 0.6 with equal probability.

Comment: @T_M  yes, you are correct.  I meant min.